# How should the Dom be in this jQuery code?

Tags: html, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="cart-plus-minus">
  <input class="cart-plus-minus-box quantity" id="{{ $item->id }}" name="quantity[{{ $i }}]" value="{{ $item->quantity }}" type="text">
  <input  name="product_id[{{ $i }}]" value="{{ $item->id }}" type="hidden">
  <div class="dec qtybutton" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
     <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-down"></i>
  </div>
  <div class="inc qtybutton" data-id="{{ $item->id }}">
    <i class="zmdi zmdi-chevron-up"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have this jQuery code that it does not work:

```
$('div.cart-plus-minus > div.dec').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    alert(id);
});
```

How should the dom be If I want to click on dec button and it displays an alert?

I have tried all and it does not work yet.

Thanks!

Comment: Your code is correct. Are you binding the click in document ready? Is HTML available on page when event binding is  done?

Comment: @MilindAnantwar http://54.237.7.12/ check this, it is the cart...

Comment: `$(document).on('click', 'div.cart-plus-minus > div.dec',function () {`